# Best UI approach to align the column titles of reports

Tags: gui-design, tables, info-visualisation, alignment, column-headers

I would like to know what the best approach is to align header columns according to their data type.

I haven't found any Human Design Interface articles explaining this.

Should the header column follow the same alignment that its data values uses?

[image: Example header columns following the data type alignment]

If yes, I would like to see some trustworthy references.

Comment: This [question][1] is similar and has a couple of good answers.

  [1]: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/24066/40589

Answer (score 12):

Columns of figures should be tabular and right aligned if they share the same unit, and the headings should match.

Guidelines, via Morten Hjerde ([IXDA thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302002717/http://www.ixda.org/node/14818)):

> - All text left aligned
> - All numbers right aligned
> - Single characters are centered
> - Numbers that are not values, like product codes for example, are treated
>   like text and left aligned.
> - Use the same number of decimal places for all numbers in a column
> - Left align dates.
> - Use 2 digits and leading zero for day numbers (this may be cultural?), and use
>   the same format for dates throughout

I'm not able to find any Tufte-esque references, but plenty of examples:

<strike>I had to take out additional links and images because I don't have the rep yet. Sorry friend :\</strike>

Hoefler & Co., from a more print design-focused perspective, provide a reasonable example ([source](http://www.typography.com/techniques/fonts-for-financials/)):

[image: H&FJ]

Example two (pulled from [this](http://www.behance.net/gallery/UHAUL-Annual-Report-2010/1064319) Behance profile). Just clear enough to tell what's going on:

[image: UHAUL report]

Answer (score 4):

In general, Excel is considered the grand-daddy of data grid applications, and most apps with data tables generally follow it's basic defaults. So, titles, dates and text usually align to the left and numerical values generally align to the right. Column headers always align to the left regardless of data type.

Comment: +1 It's an interesting question though.  Just because Excel does it that way doesn't mean it is good UX.  Although it does give an idea of what people may unconsciously expect.

Comment: Titles, Dates, and other text align to the left for easier scanning.  Scanning numerical values is easier with right alignment.  Users are still scanning the left side of the column.  Comparing the magnitude of values is easier with left alignment (e.g., 15,000 vs 3,000 with right alignment reads as 150 vs _30 when visually scanning the first 3 characters).  If it helps, you can think of numerical values as being left aligned, but with leading 0s replaced by spaces.  The most important information is still on the left.

Comment: In Excel, the header column does not know what kind of values are below. So it's up to the creator of the spreadsheet to properly format the heading.

Answer (score 4):

- Numerical data is right-aligned.
- Textual data is left-aligned because is read from left-to-right.
- Headers are aligned with their data and center alignment is not recommended.

I know that this question is from 5 years ago, but I saw it has no answer and I found this article, ["Design Better Data Tables"](https://medium.com/mission-log/design-better-data-tables-430a30a00d8c#.j9z5vt1l1) very detailed and complete as an answer.

> Numerical data is read right-to-left; that is, we compare numbers by
>   first looking at their ones digit, then their tens, then their
>   hundreds, and so on. This is also how most people learn
>   arithmetic — start on the right and move left, carrying digits as you
>   go[1](https://medium.com/mission-log/design-better-data-tables-430a30a00d8c#.j9z5vt1l1). Therefore, tables should keep numerical data right-aligned.
>
> Textual data is read (in English) from left-to-right. Comparing
>   textual elements is typically done by sorting into alphabetical order:
>   if two entries start with the same letter, the second letter is used,
>   and so on. Trying to quickly scan text can be infuriating if it’s not
>   left-aligned.
>
> Headers, generally, should carry whatever alignment their data has.
>   This keeps the vertical lines of the table clean, and provides
>   consistency and context.
>
> Center alignment causes the lines of the table to become “ragged,”
>   which makes it much harder to scan entries, often necessitating extra
>   dividers and graphical elements.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I recall a professors' advice years ago that I use:

- if it would/could be summed up or added or is currency or quantity, right align
- if it's text or sentences or words, generally left align
- if the cells are compared between rows or typically scanned for differences, center align it (like part numbers, warehouse numbers, codes, units of measure, etc.) but not if there's a lot of text that the user has to read
- if it's something like a line number for an order, for example, left align or center align, but left is probably best if it's sequential data
- if it's dates and they're uniform (ie: 2020/01/02) then center align so the eye can scan easily, but if the dates are irregular (ie: 2020/1/2 or Jan 2, 2020) then left align
- fonts can change things, a bad font may mean you have to make exceptions to the rules to save the user's eyes

Answer (score 0):

I think dwils makes an interesting point. His examples look like they reference the print world of accounts. I've used design principles from these visualisations in HTML data tables/grids I've developed. Principles such as columns that contain numerical data are right aligned as is the header, columns that have a sub heading are centred across the span.

Take a look at how [banks](https://home.barclays/content/dam/home-barclays/documents/investor-relations/annualreports/ar2011/2011-barclays-bank-plc-annual-report.pdf) and [building societies](https://www.nationwide.co.uk/-/assets/nationwidecouk/documents/about/how-we-are-run/results-and-accounts/2011-2012/annual-report-2012.pdf?rev=750596155cea41a1aa6ecdd6731ae19f&hash=C027351C7DA11D196227B0625F890B1D) present their annual reports. The reports present visual consistency in their tabular formats.